# WPF Flexibility with error with STA thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I want to show window, but i got an error "The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this". I found the sollution, but it's awfut to write this every time.

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action) delegate
{
    msgBox =
        new CustomMessageBox(
            "Файл добавлен в базу, строки " + errors +
            " не были добавлены по причине неверных входных данных",
            "Уведомление");
    msgBox.Show();
});
```

Are there any other sollutions? I put code of CustomMessageBoxBelow

```
public partial class CustomMessageBox : Window
{
    public CustomMessageBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public CustomMessageBox(string text, string title)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Title = title;
        TextBlock.Text = text;
    }

    private void OkBtn_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Displaying message boxes in a worker thread is very rarely a good idea, this is supposed to be awful.  If it wasn't awful then almost everybody would get it wrong.  Use BackgroundWorker or TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() instead.

Comment: Do you have the  `STAThread`  attribute at the main method?

Answer (score 1):

As the WPF application is `STA` application, all the logic which deals with UI controls must run inside the context of the UI thread. This is exactly `Dispatcher` being used for - call the method into a UI simchronization context.

I agree that the code you've provided isn't nice, so you have to refactor it. I suggest you to create a method which will be run in background, returning the status of the operation, which can include the error codes and warnings.

The code could be something like this:

```
async void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // get string result of the operation
    var result = await Task.Run(() => SaveTheData());
    if (result != "OK")
    {
        msgBox = new CustomMessageBox(
                    "Файл добавлен в базу, строки " + result +
                    " не были добавлены по причине неверных входных данных",
                    "Уведомление");
        msgBox.Show();
    }
}
```

Other thing I wanted to say is that you probably should check the users input **before** it's being saved to the database, which could save their time.

Answer (score 0):

Create a helper function and invoke the message box asynchronously on the UI thread:

```
static void ThreadSafeMessageBox(String text)
{
  Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => MessageBox.Show(text)));
}

void Test()
{
  Task.Run(() => { ThreadSafeMessageBox("Hi!");});
}
```